# ListPreferences in android

Tags: android, listpreference

I am trying to populate a list from `ListPreferences`

xml code

```
<ListPreference
 android:title="Countries"
 android:summary="Select the country"
 android:key="listPref"
 android:defaultValue="1"/>
```

and in `ListPreferenceActivity` pass the String arrays as:

```
ListPreference lp = (ListPreference)findPreference("listPref");
lp.setEntries(entries);
lp.setEntryValues(entryValues);
```

This is not working and I am getting this Error:

> 12-26 14:47:32.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.

Comment: actually problem get solved.I was passing wrong array.